# Syntax examples for use of typing.List?

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

I read parts of [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) and tried googling, but still feel pretty in the dark on basic syntax of how to use the data structures from the typing module.

```
from typing import List
A = List[int]
```

So once I've done the above, how do I even add new elements to A? I tried A += 5, A += [5], A.append(5), A.append([5])... I usually don't try to just haphazardly explore syntax, but I can't find much information online. Is there some syntax examples or tutorial page somewhere I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: "how do I even add new elements to A" - you don't. You've made a type alias, not a list. Did you *want* a list?

Comment: `typing` doesn't provide *data structures*, it provides special-purpose objects that are supposed to serve as *type hints*. This is for people that are 1) reading the source code 2) third-party libraries, particularly for static analysis.

Comment: Some external related reading: [PEP 484 -- Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) and [typing — Support for type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)